# Convert from start/end date to cumulate events per time period

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape, tidyr

The end goal is to visualize the amount of a medication taken per day across a large sample of individuals. I'm trying to reshape my data to make a stacked area chart (or something similar).

In a more general term; I have my data structured as below:

```
id med     start_date  end_date
1  drug_a  2010-08-24  2011-03-03
2  drug_a  2011-06-07  2011-08-12
3  drug_b  2010-03-26  2010-10-31
4  drug_b  2012-08-14  2013-01-31
5  drug_c  2012-03-01  2012-06-20
5  drug_a  2012-04-01  2012-06-14
```

I think I'm trying to create a data frame with one row per date, and a column summing the total of patients (`id`) that are taking that drug on that day. For example, if someone is taking `drug_a` from `2010-01-01` to `2010-01-20`, each of those drug-days should count.

Something like:

```
date       drug_a   drug_b   drug_c
2010-01-01      5        0       10
2010-01-02     10        2        8
```

I'm functional with dplyr and tidyr, but unsure how to use spread with dates and durations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd expand out the data to use all dates using a do loop:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(zoo)

df %>%
  group_by(id, med) %>%
  do(with(.,
          data_frame(
            date = (start_date:end_date) %>% as.Date) ) ) %>%
  group_by(date, med) %>%
  summarize(frequency = n() ) %>%
  spread(med, frequency)
```

Comment: thanks! two small changes I found useful. first, my dates were POSIXct, so I used `date=(seq.POSIXt(from=start_date, to=end_dateest, by="day"))`, as the code you showed tried to sum my results over seconds. Also, I added `fill=0` to the spread function, as I am generating structural zeroes.